# TypeError: $$invalidate(...) is not a function in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

I have a carousel which displays reviews. When clicking on a button, I get this error:

```
TypeError: $$invalidate(...) is not a function
```

Strangely, everything works, so nothing is broken. But I can't fathom where this error is coming from or what causes it. Here is the code:

```
<script>
    let showntestimonial = 1;
    const testimonials = [ { // array of objects } ];
</script>

<section class="customer-testimonial">
  <button
    class="arrowbox"
    on:click={() => (showntestimonial += 2)((showntestimonial = showntestimonial % 3))}>
    <i class="far fa-chevron-left" />
  </button>
  <div class="textbox">
    <p>
      {@html testimonials[showntestimonial].text[$language]}
    </p>
    <h2>
      {@html testimonials[showntestimonial].name}
    </h2>
  </div>
  <button
    class="arrowbox"
    on:click={() => (showntestimonial++)((showntestimonial = showntestimonial % 3))}>
    <i class="far fa-chevron-right" />
  </button>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a Svelte error, it's an error in your code. When you write this...

```js
(showntestimonial++)((showntestimonial = showntestimonial % 3))
```

...you're saying 'call `showntestimonial++` with the argument `(showntestimonial % 3)`'. But `showntestimonial++` isn't a function, it's a number — you can't call it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The strangest thing for is that it worked beside the error.

Comment: That's to be expected — the `showntestimonial++` expression will evaluate first, then the `showntestimonial = showntestimonial % 3`, then the `$$invalidate(...)` call that Svelte injects, and only *then* will it try (and fail) to call the function

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I still don't know the exact source of the problem, but I was able to fix it by using a "normal" function syntax instead of that fancy one. So the code which fixes the error is this:

```
  <button
    class="arrowbox"
    on:click={() => {
      showntestimonial += 2;
      showntestimonial = showntestimonial % 3;
    }}>
    <i class="far fa-chevron-left" />
  </button>
```